# Max and min value of $7x+8y$ in a given half-plane limited by straight lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, analytic-geometry, linear-programming

So, there are four inequalities:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
y &\geq &-3x+15; \\
y &\leq &-11/3x+56/3; \\
x &\geq &0; \\
y &\geq &0.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

If we draw all those half-planes, we get a section half-plane where all of them have a solution ($x$ and $y$). But, how can I find $\max$ and $\min$ value of $7x+8y$ in that section?

Comment: This is a linear programming optimizing problem. Retagged as such. See [this](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/linprog.htm) introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment above the stated optimization problem is solved
normally by linear programming. Since the constraints involve only two
variables, it has a simple geometric interpretation. The conditions
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
-3x+15 &\leq &y\leq -11/3x+56/3;  \tag{1} \\
x &\geq &0,\quad y\geq 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
define the quadrilateral $Q$ (dark green in the figure below) whose vertices are
$$
\begin{equation*}
A\left( 0,15\right) ,B\left( 0,56/3\right) ,C\left( 56/11,0\right) ,D\left(
5,0\right) .
\end{equation*}
$$
Let 
$$
\begin{equation}
z=7x+8y.\tag{2} 
\end{equation}
$$
The equation $$7x+8y=c,\tag{3} $$ where $c$ is a parameter, defines the family of parallel lines in the $xy$-plane whose slope is $-7/8$. The larger $c$ is, the higher the $y$-intercept $c/8$ is. One of these is the blue line of the figure, whose equation is $7x+8y=0$ (i.e. $c=0$). To find $\max z$ subject to the constraints $(1)$ it is enough to compute $z$ at the vertex $B$, because from all the lines of the form $(3)$ with at least a common point to $Q$ the one through $B$ has the maximum value of the parameter $c$, as can be seen in the figure (light green line).

[image]

Similarly to find $\min z$ subject to the same constraints $(1)$ we compute $z$ at the vertex $D(5,0)$, because from all the lines of the family $(3)$ with at least a common point to $Q$ it is the one through $D$ (red line) that yields the minimum value for $c$. So
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{Q}{\max }z &=&7\left( 0\right) +8\left( 56/3\right) =\frac{448}{3}
\approx 149.33 \\
\underset{Q}{\min }z &=&7\left( 5\right) +8\left( 0\right) =35.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: @A6Tech You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You get the domain in the first quadrant (inequalities 3-4) between the lines

$$y=-3x+15\;,\;\;y=-\frac{11}{3}x+\frac{56}{3}$$

The maximum-minimum values of your target function $\,f(x,y):=7x+8y\,$ within this domain are thus obtained on the *vertices* of the above domain, which are the points

$$(0,15)\,,\,\left(0,\frac{56}{3}\right)\,,\,\,(5,0)\,,\,\,\left(\frac{56}{11},0\right)$$

Now you only need to evaluate your function in each of the above points and choose the highest and lowest value.

**Why** this works this way is the basis of Linear Programming, and requires some linear algebra and stuff.